# Can I use a node module such as require('npm-package') with nextjs vercel, google-cloud-speech

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel, google-speech-api

I'd like to use google cloud speech with my nextjs vercel applicaiton, but having trouble importing the module`

```
const speech = require('google-cloud/speech');
```

I tried configuring the webpack5 file, but not getting anything logged for the speech

```
//next.config.js
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({  \
  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { 'google-cloud/speech': false };

    return config;
  },
})
```

any help would be appreciated

api/route file

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const speech = require('google-cloud/speech');



export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  console.log(speech, 'lx')
  const body = await req.json();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/speech) is the package you're attempting to use, then you should refer to it with `@google-cloud/speech` in your import. Note the `@`. You should double check you've installed it correctly by running `npm i @google-cloud/speech`.

Additionally, it looks like you're using ES syntax (see [es vs commonjs imports](https://dev.to/lico/how-to-import-and-export-in-commonjs-and-es-modules-43m1)) in your route file, so you should actually import the module like this:

```js
import speech from '@google-cloud/speech'
```

Then, I would recommend reading up on its documentation for how to correctly use it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/speech). Best of luck!